# dplyr with name of columns in a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Not able to figure out how to use column names in a function using `dplyr` `R` package. Reproducible example is below:

**Data**

```
set.seed(12345)
Y <- rnorm(10)
Env <- paste0("E", rep(1:2, each = 5))
Gen <- paste0("G", rep(1:5, times = 2))
df1 <- data.frame(Y, Env, Gen)
```

**Works outside function**

```
library(dplyr)
  df1 %>%
    dplyr::group_by(E, G) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(mean(Y))

with(data = df1, expr = tapply(X = Y, INDEX = list(E, G), FUN = mean))
```

**First function**

```
fn1 <- function(Y, E, G, data){
  Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))
  E <- deparse(substitute(E))
  G <- deparse(substitute(G))
  Out <- with(data = data, tapply(X = Y, INDEX = list(E, G), FUN = mean), parent.frame())
  return(Out)
}  

fn1(Y = Y, E = Env, G = Gen, data = df1)
```

> Error in tapply(X = Y, INDEX = list(E, G), FUN = mean) :    arguments
>   must have same length

**Second function**

```
fn2 <- function(Y, E, G, data){
  Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))
  E <- deparse(substitute(E))
  G <- deparse(substitute(G))
  library(dplyr)
  Out <- df1 %>%
    dplyr::group_by(E, G) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(mean(Y))
  return(Out)
}  

fn2(Y = Y, E = Env, G = Gen, data = df1)
```

> Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :    Column `E` is
>   unknown

Comment: What is `E` and `G` from your **Data**??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would to use the `enquo` to capture the expression and its environment in a `quosure` object which can be evaluated within the `group_by`, `summarise`, `mutate` etc by using `!!` operator or `UQ` (unquote expression)

```
fn2 <- function(Y, E, G, data){
 E <- enquo(E)
 G <- enquo(G)
 Y <- enquo(Y)
 data %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!! E, !! G) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Y = mean(!!Y))

}

fn2(Y, E = Env, G = Gen, df1)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups: Env [?]
#   Env    Gen         Y
#   <fctr> <fctr>  <dbl>
# 1 E1     G1      0.586
# 2 E1     G2      0.709
# 3 E1     G3     -0.109
# 4 E1     G4     -0.453
# 5 E1     G5      0.606
# 6 E2     G1     -1.82 
# 7 E2     G2      0.630
# 8 E2     G3     -0.276
# 9 E2     G4     -0.284
#10 E2     G5     -0.919
```

---

In the Op's function, while the expression is captured by `substitute`, with `deparse`, it is converted to a string.  By using `sym` from `rlang`, this can be converted to symbol and then evaluated with `!!` or `UQ` as above

```
fn2 <- function(Y, E, G, data){
   Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))
   E <- deparse(substitute(E))
   G <- deparse(substitute(G))

   df1 %>%
    dplyr::group_by(!!rlang::sym(E), !! rlang::sym(G)) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(Y = mean(!! rlang::sym(Y)))

}  

fn2(Y = Y, E = Env, G = Gen, data = df1)
```

Another variant of the OP's function without using `rlang` would be to make use of `group_by_at` or `summarise_at` which can take strings as argument

```
fn3 <- function(Y, E, G, data){
  Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))
  E <- deparse(substitute(E))
  G <- deparse(substitute(G))

   df1 %>%
    dplyr::group_by_at(vars(E, G)) %>%
    dplyr::summarize_at(vars(Y), mean)

}  

fn3(Y = Y, E = Env, G = Gen, data = df1)
```

Comment: Would highly appreciate if you explain your answer and problem in my code. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208  I added couple of other options and some explanations